# Calculating Categorical Raster Areas per Polygon

Tags: raster, grass-gis, spatial-statistics, raster-conversion

I've got forest fragmentation data from which I've extracted pixels that correspond to forest edges and patches. I've also got a shapefile of counties in a US state. I'm trying to get the area of edges and patches within each county but can't figure out a good way to do it.

The only way I can think of is to vectorize the raster in GRASS and then obtain the area of categories through the resultant polygons. I've tried going through this process in GRASS but it has been running for at least 6 hours and the vector data is extremely large already, taking ~3GB and counting.

Do any of you know of another way to obtain categorical pixel areas per polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the other way round : converting your counties to raster, then use [r.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.stats.html) to cross the two rasters.

Comment: I'll try that. For the county data, I keep the 254 rows identified by FIPS codes. Won't this result in a very large cross-tab?

Comment: Figured it out that was so much better and faster than what I was originally trying to do! Accepted. Thanks!